# How to query and fetch just partial attributes using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

1. How to fetch Foo.id alone for multiple documents in an index
2. How to fetch Foo.bi for multiple documents in an index

Sample response from Spring Data Elasticsearch for Page is given below

"content": [
{
"id": "MMb-sHUBU93O1WjGd0M1",
"pid": "12500000",
"bi": {
"bar": 27,
"height": {
"feet": 5,
"inches": 6,
},
},
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to retrieving partial attributes, use `_source`:

```
GET /_search
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "Foo.id",
      "Foo.bi"
    ],
    "excludes": []
  }
}
```

Regarding

> How to query just partial attributes

you're sending a query againt the whole index in ES and the `query` parameter enables you to filter concrete fields so it does not really make sense to talk about querying *partial attributes* -- that's what the `query` already does.